# can't find antlr3 on running dev_appserver.py

Tags: python, google-app-engine, antlr3

When I am trying to run myproject with google app engine,using

```
python google_appengine/dev_appserver.py myproject
```

it is giving me an error --

```
Import Error: No Module Named antlr3
```

I have installed antlr3. and it is there in the lib directory....

any help would be appreciated...

Comment: I have the same error `monas-mbp:arff-1.0c mona$ ls
MANIFEST.in PKG-INFO arff.g  pysource setup.py
monas-mbp:arff-1.0c mona$ python setup.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 45, in <module>
    from pysource.version import Version
  File "/Users/mona/Downloads/arff-1.0c/pysource/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from arff import *
  File "/Users/mona/Downloads/arff-1.0c/pysource/arff.py", line 35, in <module>
    from antlr3 import CommonTokenStream as CTS, ANTLRInputStream as AIS
ImportError: No module named antlr3`